# SQL Trim everything from first and last string indicator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to clean a column containing unwanted tags in SQL.

**The data looks like this:**

```
<"blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text*  <"/blockquote>
"I must remain" <"blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text again*<"/blockquote>
"I must remain, too" <"blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text again*<"/blockquote>
```

I want to remove everything starting from *<"blockquote* until *<"/blockquote>* that the cleaned data will become:
"I must remain" "I must remain, too"

I want to do this to be a SQL Function for data cleansing.

**I want to remove all the string starting from *<"blockquote* until *<"/blockquote>* then retain those string not contained between them.

Please help.

Comment: Does this really have to be done with T-SQL? This seems like a task for something more geared to string handling and that can take advantage of regular expressions. In T-SQL you're going to have a really ugly expression that is difficult to troubleshoot and performs like molasses.

Comment: I'm not really sure SQL Server is the right choice for it; string manipulation is not it's forté. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Seems you beat me to the same thought @AaronBertrand.

Comment: Hello, yes, the records are stored in sql database and the column contains html texts and other tags. I already tried CHARINDEX before and that worked, and unfortunately I lost my code that does what I want right now :(

Comment: I'd suggest you get back to rewriting it then. If you had a solution that worked and you didn't save it, then you know better than us what you previously did.

Comment: Why don't you stop it at the source or create a new column to store the required text only from the source ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand please checkout my answer. It can be done simple :)

Comment: @Juozas Well, I addressed both simplicity and speed, and while we could debate whether simplicity implies intuitiveness or just character length, your solution assumes that the only possible use case is the example in the question, where the OP wants to remove *all* the HTML elements in the sample data, which only represents one row. What if there are other HTML entities that are to be kept (like `<span>`, `<img>`, etc.)? This is why I think RegEx would be safer and more applicable, especially if the OP left out other cases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no problems with span, img. But, it is some kind of cheeting, and your proposed solution is really safer

Comment: @Juozas There is a problem. `<span> should stay </span> other stuff <blockquote></blockquote><img />`. When I feed this to your approach, everything is gone except for `other stuff`. From the wording in the question, I gather that the format provided there is not the only format that will be possible in their table, and that there will be other content that needs to be kept.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this. @data is your string:

```
declare @data_xml xml = replace(@data, '<"', '<');
select convert(nvarchar(max), @data_xml.query('text()'));
```

Full query: https://pastebin.com/mJpfmYyQ

Comment: More gooder, especially with the XML.  I suspect  the replace was not necessary because OP had a formatting issue.  +1

Answer (score 1):

If open to a TVF...

Tired of extracting strings (left,right,patindex,substrings,...), I modified a parse function to accept two non-like delimiters

Being a TVF, it is easy to use within a `CROSS APPLY` or as a stand-alone.

Also not clear on your desired results.  If you want one string rather than records, you can easily consolidate it via XML STUFF() method.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text*  </blockquote>"I must remain" <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text again*</blockquote>"I must remain, too" <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text again*</blockquote>'

Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'blockquote>','<blockquote')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1       77      "I must remain" 
2       173     "I must remain, too"
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to obtain my desired outcome using the query below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(VAL VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @Tbl VALUES('<"blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text*  <"/blockquote>
"I must remain" <"blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text again*<"/blockquote>
"I must remain, too" <"blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"> *some text again*<"/blockquote>');
SELECT 1; --initialize @@ROWCOUNT if necessary. Might be optional depending on need
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE @Tbl
    SET VAL = STUFF(VAL,CHARINDEX('<"blockquote',VAL),CHARINDEX('<"/blockquote>',VAL) - CHARINDEX('<"blockquote',VAL) + 14,'')
    WHERE VAL LIKE '%<%>%'
END
SELECT * FROM @Tbl;
```

Comment: @EzLo Perks of high rep, I am wanting to edit it like this, but the system wont let me.

Comment: Now I need a good translation for this to become a SQL Function